# What exactly is the difference between company users and Azure AD users?

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, office365

I'm relatively new to the whole Microsoft environment and this has been tickling my brain for a while. What exactly is the difference between company users present, for example, in the Microsoft 365 admin center and on AzureAD for propery-editting purposes? Are they both synced together, do they serve different purposes? Most powershell scripts I find to retrieve, for example, all users and properties use cmdlets such as Get-AzureADuser, hence the question.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are the same.

The basic attributes of the users are stored in Azure AD and you can use Microsoft Graph to query them easily.

The difference between them is:

In O365 admin center, you can manage the access to resources under O365 subscriptions. For example: Exchange Online, SharePoint online, Teams Online and so on. But in Azure Portal, you can manage the access to resources under Azure subscription, such as Azure web app, Azure AD app registration, Azure VM, Azure security group and so on.

The company users indeed are Azure AD users. It's just called differently according to the environment (O365 or Azure AD).

`Get-AzureADuser` is under Azure AD PowerShell  Module. You can also use `Get-MsolUser` which is under MSOnline PowerShell Module (it's old O365 Module) to get the users.

Comment: Perfect this is exactly what I needed, thank you so much!!

Comment: As a follow-up, using the Azure module and applying changes to users' properties will then mirror them when pulling them with the MSOnline module